# C++ G711 encoder decoder error

Tags: c++, function, build-error

I have the following code in C++ ( Visual Studio 2013 ) to declare a function prototype in a header file:

```
extern "C" __cdecl
short int
G_Init(
 void *Ptr,
 char Encoding);
```

and the compiler returns the following error:

`error C2062: type 'short' unexpected`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx): *"Place the `__cdecl` modifier **before a variable or a function name**."*

That is, `extern "C" short int __cdecl G_Init`, not `extern "C" __cdecl short int
G_Init`.